# Why Angulars JS gives error in URL routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I use routeProvider in Angular JS. My links look as:

```
www.site.com/profile#/profile/profession/3
```

Angular JS tells that was error in page:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .nav-tabs a[href=#/profile/profession/3]
```

Comment: it should be `.nav-tabs a[href="#/profile/profession/3"]` instead of `.nav-tabs a[href=#/profile/profession/3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add quote to you href expression like this

```
.nav-tabs a[href="#/profile/profession/3"]
```

Comment: I use: `href="#/profile/profession/3">Profession</a>`

Comment: The problem is occurring in a jquery selector. You are doing something like `$(".nav-tabs a[href=#/profile/profession/3]` and you should do `$(".nav-tabs a[href='#/profile/profession/3']`

Answer (score 2):

```
.nav-tabs a[href="#/profile/profession/3"]
```

Double quotes should use in the href.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented your style needs to be changed to

**From**

`.nav-tabs a[href=#/profile/profession/3]`

**To**

`.nav-tabs a["href=#/profile/profession/3"]`

Comment: Problem is that I have not element `nav-tabs` in page. Only links: `<a href="#/profile/profession/3">Profession</a>`

Comment: Problem is not resolved, I still get error with a link taht I posted

Comment: Do you mean to remove `"`? like as: `href=#/profile/profession/3>Profession</a>` ?

Comment: @Hamed  try `'` instead of double quotes `"` if you are adding this from script `href='#/profile/profession/3'>Profession</a>`